# Run a function on every page load

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to figure out how to trigger a function on every each page load. Let me give an example of the function and the desired outcome. Right now I have code that does the following:

```
//I don't think you need to see the actual code.
private function last_user_purging
  if last_purge timestamp is at least 5 minutes ago
    return TRUE

if function last_user_purging = TRUE
  delete users who missed their 5 min window to activate their acc.
```

I have this code inside each `public function index()` in all my controllers. But this means that the entire block of code is only triggered once the user is on the index of each of the controllers. Since they can be just navigating through various views inside the controller they won't activate the code.

Therefore, I would like to know where I should put this code to make sure it is triggered on each page load no matter the controller and their views. Hope this makes sense.

BTW: I know the best would be to have Cron run the function every 5 minutes after a user triggers the registration function, but I don't have the tools to do so..

Answer (score 0):

**For CodeIgniter 3.1.9**

**Option 1:** you can override the core controller according to this page : https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/core_classes.html

**Option 2:** you can call your fonction or some lines of code in the constructors of each controller:

```
public function __construct() 
{
    parent::__construct();

    // My stuff
    echo 'Hello !';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Place this function in

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    // Your code here
}
```

This way your code will be checked, no matter which function within this class is called.

Comment: But I still have to repeat the code in every controller right?

Comment: Try extend `CI_Controller` and put your magic in that constructor. This is how it is [done](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2010/02/CodeIgniter-Base-Classes-Keeping-it-DRY).

Comment: That is what I am doing, but that means I need to put it in every controller. Like I would meet to open the CI_Controller itself and put it there, but that does not seem like a good practice

Comment: you put it in MY_Controller which extends CI_Controller and that is good practice.